# Typescript : optional parameter in mapped types

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to implement a mapped type with some parameters required and some optional.

The following code works for required parameters but I can't use the optional ones.

```js
type Foo = { foo: string }

const A_FIELD_REQ = ['x', 'y'] as const
const A_FIELD_OPT = ['z'] as const

const B_FIELD_REQ = ['x', 'y', 'z'] as const
const B_FIELD_OPT = [] as const

type QueryA = {
  type: 'a'
  fields: { [field in typeof A_FIELD_REQ[number]]: Foo | undefined }
}

type QueryB = {
  type: 'b'
  fields: { [field in typeof B_FIELD_REQ[number]]: Foo | undefined }
}

type Query = {
  id: string
} & (QueryA | QueryB)

const myQueries: Query[] = [
  {
    id: '0',
    type: 'a',
    fields: {
      x: { foo: '' },
      y: { foo: '' },
    },
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    type: 'a',
    fields: {
      x: undefined, // valid
      y: { foo: '' },
    },
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    type: 'b',
    fields: {
      x: { foo: '' },
      y: { foo: '' },
      z: { foo: '' },
    },
  },
]
```

#### How I would like to use my types

I should be able to handle an optional parameter in the same key `fields` from my `Query` type. Exactly like a basic `z?: Foo | undefined`.

```js
const myQueries = [
  {
    id: '0',
    type: 'a',
    fields: {
      x: { foo: '' },
      y: { foo: '' },
    },
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    type: 'a',
    fields: {
      x: undefined, // valid
      y: { foo: '' },
    },
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    type: 'b',
    fields: {
      x: { foo: '' },
      y: { foo: '' },
      z: { foo: '' },
    },
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    type: 'a',
    fields: {
      x: { foo: '' },
      y: { foo: '' },
      z: { foo: '' }, // !!! optional parameter !!!
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `?` optional modifier

```js
type QueryA = {
  type: 'a'
  fields: { [field in typeof A_FIELD_REQ[number]]?: Foo }
}

type QueryB = {
  type: 'b'
  fields: { [field in typeof B_FIELD_REQ[number]]?: Foo }
}
```